# laravel 5.4 : Laravelcollective/html v5.3.0 requires illuminate/view 5.3.*

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravelcollective

I was using `Laravelcollective/html v5.3.0` with `laravel 5.3`. Now i am using `laravel 5.4`. I have forms which are using `Laravelcollective/html v5.3.0`.

The `composer require laravelcollective/html` gives me the following error:

```
Installation request for laravelcollective/html ^5.3 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.3.0].
-Conclusion: remove laravel/frameworkv5.4.0
 - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
```

**When gonna laravel 5.4 support `Laravelcollective/html` ?**

Comment: Already there are two issues files in `Laravelcollective/html` github page. You may have to check that

Comment: what Cerlin Boss and PaladiN say is correct. just a bit correction to your question, *When gonna laravel 5.4 support Laravelcollective/html ?* i suppose it should be LaravelCollective/html supports Laravel 5.4..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update:**

The Laravelcollective/html has been updated to `Laravel 5.4` but there is no any changes in the documentation till now.
If you want to see the pull request it is right here:

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/276

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/284

Just use:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4"
```

Or,

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

If you don't want to specify the version and get the same latest version of LaravelCollective.

**Older Issue:**

`Laravelcollective/html v5.3.0` requires Laravel 5.3 and not yet supports `Laravel 5.4`.

The `laravelcollective/html v5.4` is under open issue:

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/276

It could be merged any time.

Just have an eye on it.

**Edit:**

**Alternatively you could use `maddhatter's` git repository as he had done some changes that is not yet provided in `git@github.com:st3f/html.git` repository.**

Just add it into your `composer.json`

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/maddhatter/html.git"
        }
],
"require": {
     "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.x-dev",
}
```

and run

> composer update

**Or, if you don't need those changes you could follow `Cerlin Boss` answer**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41845331/3887342

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Will not post such kinda question again :)

Comment: @Gamer The solution has been updated. Now `LaravelCollective` supports `Laravel 5.4`

Comment: Awesome buddy, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE: This answer was posted when `laravelcollective/html` was not supporting `laravel 5.4`**

For dev purpose you can use the origin repo from the pull request for [5.4](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/276/)

Configure the repo

```
"repositories": {
    "laravelcollective": {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:st3f/html.git"
    }
}
```

To add this automatically without manually editing the `composer.json`
run,

```
composer config repositories.laravelcollective vcs git@github.com:st3f/html.git
```

Require the `dev-master` as it has the changes for 5.4

```
"laravelcollective/html": "dev-master"
```

Once the original repo author releases the support for 5.4, just remove the `vcs` repo reference and change the `dev-master` to `5.4`

Comment: Bro i am having a bit difficulty, how to configure the repo ?

Comment: it should be added to `composer.json`. Alternatively you can run this command in console `composer config repositories.laravelcollective vcs git@github.com:st3f/html.git`