# Laravel: form, html FormFacade class not working in 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.3

Is there any way to install FormFacade class for 5.4. I 've tried via composer.json as well as vie command prompt.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using the 5.3 version of it? and it failed for you? `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"` ? don't forget to register the service provider. here is a referrence: [Docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html)

Comment: yes as per https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html url 
also try to make it 5.4 but did't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravelcollective/html v5.3.0 requires Laravel 5.3 and not yet supports Laravel 5.4

Version `v5.4` of `laravelcollective` is under open issue on [Github](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/276)

For dev purpose check this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845042/laravel-5-4-laravelcollective-html-v5-3-0-requires-illuminate-view-5-3/41845331?noredirect=1#comment70875218_41845331) out